# boostrap validator on same page with mutiple forms

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, bootstrapvalidator

I am having a page with 2 forms "register" class "sup", and "login" class "si", 
I use the classes to create boostrap modal:

```
    $(".si").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".si_section").show();
        $(".sup").hide();
        $(".modal-header h4 span").html("@Resources.SignIn");
    });
```

They are having some common fields. username, password...

So i load the scipts to call bootstrapvalidator for each of them:

```
    $('#form-login').bootstrapValidator({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        feedbackIcons: {
            //valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            use_email: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: '@Resources.required'
                    },
                    emailAddress: {
                        message: '@Resources.loginfailuremessage'
                    }
                }
            },
            use_password: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: '@Resources.required'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // Form validator for registration
    $('form-registration').bootstrapValidator({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            use_email: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: '@Resources.required'
                    },
                    emailAddress: {
                        message: '@Resources.loginfailuremessage'
                    }
                }
            },
            Password: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: '@Resources.required'
                    },
                    emailAddress: {
                        message: '@Resources.loginfailuremessage'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

But it doesn' t work, only first one is validate, what' s my mistake ? How can i do it ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I end up doing inline editor as the multiple forms validitions is having an issue in my case